# How to update lambda function from s3 zip

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and trying to update a lambda function. The lambda function is initially created using cloud-formation template with s3key as name of my zip file present in s3 bucket.

```
 "LambdaFunction":{
         "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
         "Properties" : {
             "Code" : {
               "S3Bucket" : {
                  "Ref":"myBucket"
               },
               "S3Key" : "lambdaFunction.zip"
             },
             "FunctionName" : "HandleUserRequests",
             "Handler" : "index.handler",
             "Role" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaIamRole", "Arn"] },
             "Runtime" : "nodejs10.x",
```

Now I have updated the function in local and triggered CI/CD to upload the updated code zip onto S3 bucket.

I need to update my lambda function with this new zip upload from s3. Can you please guide, how does deployment work for lambda function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally we wouldn’t want to deploy Lambda functions using CloudFormation. We should be using [AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html).

This enables us to write and place our code locally and when u build, package and deploy the template, our code is automatically placed in S3 and linked to the Lambda function.

Comment: I am using this approach, but still finding when using AWS::Serverless::Function that the Lambda function created as part of that process is still not registering any updates to the zip file in the S3 bucket.

Comment: It’s generally always going to be a new zip file. Have u checked if your cfn template is changing and reflecting a different s3 key